# How to build an API call to a BigQuery table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would very much appreciate if anyone can point me on how to create an API call to *one specific table* on BigQuery? EG: I will send a request {user_id} and it will return {user_status}.

I've tried googling around, and the only thing I could find is two steps:

1. Export the table from BigQuery -> CSV -> postgresql on Google Cloud SQL
2. Setup API using Flask on Google App Engine that hits the DB postgresql deployed on Google Cloud SQL.

Would very much appreciate it if anyone has other more direct ways.

Thank you.

Comment: See the [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/)'s [`jobs.query`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) method. The APIs Explorer page includes a "Try this method" that allows you to prove the functionality. You can then use your preferred language [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) to develop the code.

Comment: @DazWilkin - Thanks for the help; seems we're going in the right direction. How do I call a query for a single user (eg: /api/user_id/123456)? I don't want to return the entire rows on the table. Thank you again.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean the authenticated user returning data to which they have access? This would be true by default. Or, do you mean the concept of a user in your schema? If so, then you'd have to write the query to take the `user_id` as a parameter but it would be no different than any parameter.

Comment: It is unclear what your goal / use case is. The BigQuery API is very powerful. Limiting access to a certain table can be done by using  the IAM and service accounts. If there are only a few users, you could give also each user a service account to limit what this user can see. With cloud functions it is possible to write your own REST API, which can query data in BigQuery and gives the result out. However, you need to do all security on your own, thus you could include user passworts, so that each user can only query its status and not all.

Comment: I agree with my peer. Your design and your use case aren't clear, and can lead to the wrong too to use (user status in serverless mode should take place in Firestore)

Comment: As everyone has mentioned, your question is now unclear, you can limit access via IAM roles and services account and serverless mode as Guillaume mentioned is managed via firestore.